# Typed Transformation of Datasets with mapPartitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to perform a typed transformation to replace 
all values of some columns on a Dataset. I know that this is possible using "select" but I would like to have the full dataset returned with the specific column values changed rather than just individual columns. I also know this is possible and straightforward using the withColumn method but that is considered an untyped transformation. To do the same for a typed transformation and get the full Dataset back, I'm using mapPartitions but running into issues:

```
case class Listing(street: String, zip: Int, price: Int)
val list = List(Listing("Main St", 92323, 30000), Listing("1st St", 94331, 10000),Listing("Sunset Ave", 98283, 50000))
val ds = sc.parallelize(list).toDS
val colNames = ds.columns

val newDS = ds.mapPartitions{ iter => val newDSIter = 
    for (row <- iter) yield {
      val newRow = for (i <- 0 until ds.columns.length) yield {
        if (some_condition) { 
          //using reflection to get field value since the column to be
          //processed will be dynamically known based on if condition 
          val value = row.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(colNames(i)).invoke(row).toString
          //send 'value' to some function for processing and returning new value
        } else { 
          //just return field value
          row.getClass.getDeclaredMethod(colNames(i)).invoke(row).toString
        }
      } newRow
    } 
 newDSIter
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

I changed the following line:
    newRow.as[Listing]

which shows the error

```
error: value as is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String]
```

Which tells me that a Person object is not being returned but just a collection of Strings.

Is this the correct approach to returning a full Dataset after performing a typed transformation and is type lost in the process since I'm getting a String collection back instead of a Person object?

My other question is my confusion on typed and untyped transformation. If a schema is strictly defined for a DataFrame and some transformation performed on it, why is it still considered an untyped transformation? Or, if the withColumn method is called on a Dataset (instead of a DataFrame) and the returned value converted to a Dataset, is is still considered untyped transformation?

```
val newDS = ds.withColumn("zip", some_func).as[Listing]
```

which returns a Dataset.

Edit:

Updated the Row return line (newRow) as following:

```
Listing.getClass.getMethods.find(x => x.getName == "apply" && x.isBridge).get
.invoke(Listing, newRow map (_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]): _*).asInstanceOf[Listing]
```

In spark-shell, this returns Dataset[Listing] as I need but when compiling the code with sbt, getting the error:

```
error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by first by converting the collection to the case class (see Edit) and ensuring to import spark.implicits_.